# AutoMapper can't prevent null source values if not all source properties match

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

The goal here is to ignore null source values, while not requiring the source object to have all the fields the destination object has. Preventing null seems to only work if ALL fields match between objects.

```
public class ApiStudent {
    public long Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}

public class DomainStudent {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long SchoolId { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the following mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApiStudent, DomainStudent>()   
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => !src.IsSourceValueNull));

var api = new ApiStudent();
api.Id = 123;
api.Name = null;

var domain = new DomainStudent();
domain.Id = 123;
domain.Name = "Homer Simpson"; // goal is to prevent this from being written to null

domain = Mapper.Map(api, domain);
// I get an error here saying the SchoolId mapping is missing from ApiStudent
```

If I remove the *".ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => !src.IsSourceValueNull));"* from the Mapping definition, I don't get the error, but then the .Name property will be overwritten to null. 
What am I missing here to get the AutoMapper to skip properties that exist on the destination object but not the source object?

Answer (score 8):

This solved it!

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/432

Quoting the article

We just upgraded from 3.0.0 to 3.1.0 and started getting an issue with mappings with the following definition:

> .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition(c => !c.IsSourceValueNull)); This was
>   previously functioning correctly and would not attempt to map
>   properties which did not have a source value. After the upgrade, it
>   seems that Automapper, when faced with a destination member that has
>   no matching source member, will attempt to map from the source type to
>   the destination member. This then throws a mapping exception because
>   there is no mapping definition for the source type to any of the
>   destination property types. Previously, Automapper seemed to
>   rightfully ignore members which did not have a matching source member.

```
We changed the condition line to:

.ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition(c => c.PropertyMap.SourceMember != null && !c.IsSourceValueNull));
```

Comment: Thanks mate - just what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't see the property `IsSourceValueNull` in the latest version. Do you know how to achieve this in the current version?

Comment: @MatheusLemos The Automapper dev made a comment on Automapper's github, saying that IsSourceValueNull was removed, and to use != null instead. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1406#issuecomment-229757796 HOWEVER, I will point out that this doesn't seem to fix the issue for me. I believe this is because != null is looking for items that are declared and assigned null, rather than items that are undeclared entirely, like what Adam Levitt is asking for.